# Integers $n$ such that the largest factor of $n$ is $n-6$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring

A good integer is defined if its largest factor is $n-6$. How many integers satisfy this statement?

I know that $7$, $9$ and $12$ satisfy this statement and 12 should intuitively be the upper limit of $n$. From this I can deduce that $n-6$ should be a factor of $6$. This is more gut feeling than actual maths though. I want to know if there is a more elegant way of solving this question instead of brute force and maybe even a general solution to questions of similar caliber. At the very least a way to put this is equation form. I reckon there should be one since this question is from a math competition I went to and their questions almost always have elegant answers.

Comment: As x cannot be a factor of n if  $\frac{n}{2} <x<n$ , therefore $n-6<\frac{n+1}{2}+$, so n is <13.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** If $(n-6)$ divides $n$, since $n-6$ also divides $n-6$, $n-6$ must divide $n-(n-6)$.

Comment: It was so obvious all along! I even used the Euclidean algorithm for this. However, I'm still looking for an answer that takes into account that they are looking for the greatest factor of n, as 8 satisfies the fact that n-6 is a factor but not the fact that it must be the largest factor.

Comment: @chematwork Once you find out that there are only 4 possible choices for $n$, you simply check which works.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

Let $\frac{n}{n-6}=k$ for some positive integer $k$, then

$$
k=1+\frac{6}{n-6} \Leftrightarrow n=7,8,9,12.$$
Since $n-6$ is the greatest factor of $n$, therefore $n$ is either $9$ or $12$.

**Method 2**

Assume that $n-6$ divides $n$, then there exists an integer $k$ such that
$$n=k(n-6) \Leftrightarrow n=6+\frac{6}{k-1} \Leftrightarrow k=2,3,4,7 \Leftrightarrow n=12, 9,8,7$$
Therefore $n=9$ and $12$ are the integers such that the largest factor of $n$ is $n-6$.